# Problem with complex array input arguments to Octave C++ Dynamically Linked Functions

Tags: c++, octave, mex

Consider the following simplified example:

File 1 (The Octave .m file)

```
% test_multiplyCxArrays.m

clc; clear all; close all;
pkg load signal
mkoctfile multiplyCxArrays.cpp
disp('Compiled Octave-C++ function multiplyCxArrays.cpp');

cx_one = 1+1i;
a = [cx_one; cx_one*2; cx_one*3; cx_one*4; cx_one*5];
b = [cx_one; cx_one/2; cx_one/3; cx_one/4; cx_one/5];

disp('First input vector: ');
disp(a);

disp('First input vector inside DLD: ');
cx_out = multiplyCxArrays(a,b);

disp('Output vector returned DLD: ');
disp(cx_out);
```

File 2 (The C++ DLD file)

```
// multiplyCxArrays.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include "CNDArray.h"

using namespace std;

DEFUN_DLD (multiplyCxArrays, args, nargout,
           "multiplyCxArrays is a c++ compiled example to illustrate dynamically loaded functions in octave ")
{
  ComplexNDArray cxIn1 = args(0).array_value();
  ComplexNDArray cxIn2 = args(1).array_value();
  const int cxIn1_length = cxIn1.rows();
  const int cxIn2_length = cxIn2.rows();

  std::vector<std::complex<double>> cxVec;

  std::complex<double> cx_elem1, cx_elem2;
  for(octave_idx_type i = 0; i < cxIn1_length; ++i)
  {
    cout << "i = " << i << ", cxIn1(i) = " << cxIn1(i) << endl;
    cx_elem1 = cxIn1(i);
    cx_elem2 = cxIn2(i);
    cxVec.push_back(cx_elem1*cx_elem2);
  }

  const int cxOut_length = (int)cxVec.size();

  dim_vector dv (cxOut_length, 1);
  ComplexNDArray cxOut(dv);
  dv = cxOut.dims();
  for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < cxOut_length; ++i)
  {
    cxOut(i) = cxVec[(int)i];
  }

  octave_value_list retval(nargout);
  retval(0) = octave_value(cxOut);
  return retval;
}
```

OUTPUT printout in Octave command window:

```
First input vector:
   1 + 1i
   2 + 2i
   3 + 3i
   4 + 4i
   5 + 5i
First input vector inside DLD:
i = 0, cxIn1(i) = (1,0)
i = 1, cxIn1(i) = (2,0)
i = 2, cxIn1(i) = (3,0)
i = 3, cxIn1(i) = (4,0)
i = 4, cxIn1(i) = (5,0)
Output vector returned DLD:
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
```

For some reason the first argument of the DLD **args(0).array_value()** is only returning the real part of the input complex array and zeroing out the imaginary part as you can see from the output printout for **cxIn1(i)**. Is there any way to retrieve the full complex array from the input argument list?

Comment: From tag description "Don’t use both the [matlab] and [octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
Sorry about that. Removed the [matlab] tags. Is it ok to leave the [mex] tag? I don't find any other tag for DLD functions in octave.

Comment: I think instead of `args(x).array_value()` you should use `args(x).complex_array_value()`.

Comment: @rahnema1 That worked! thank you. Do you have a link to the Octave documentation page for these DLD functions?

Comment: There is a general introduction [here](https://docs.octave.org/v7.2.0/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html). I inspected the the C++ API source `ov.h`.